# Deletei postagens antigas e o banco de dados ficou quase do mesmo tamanho

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, otimização

Tenho um banco de dados com notícias postadas desde 2015. Eu resolvi apagar as postagens, deixando apenas as dos últimos 30 dias. Com isso, esperava que o banco de dados reduzisse de tamanho e isso não aconteceu.
Veja como fiz:

No PHPMyAdmin, acessei a tabela, fui na aba para digitar comandos SQL e apaguei os registros com o comando:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'post'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 30
```

Depois otimizei todo o banco de dados e eis que o banco está quase do mesmo tamanho.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

É assim que funciona e não deveria mexer nisso, o espaço liberado será reusado, isso é uma forma do banco de dados trabalhar melhor, então deixe assim, essa tal otimização será de espaço, mas piorará outras questões.

Se precisar muito fazer algo tem o comando [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html). É um processo complexo, demorado, precisa do dobro do espaço que o DB está ocupando agora para realizar, portanto se tiver isso é porque não precisa realizar a operação.

Se a configuração `innodb_file_per_table` estiver desligada a operação não dará resultado. E mudar demanda trabalho e cuidado.

Isso vale para Innodb, não para MyISAM ou outro *engine*.

Comment: Obrigado. É uma pena que seja assim. Você sabe me dizer se é possível, via linha de comando no ssh, em vez de subir uma tabela baixada em .sql, subir um xml do banco de dados? Se sim, qual seria o comando, supondo que o banco se chame expressao_bd e a tabela expressao_bd?

Comment: Isso é outra questão pode fazer em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. Veja o [tour] inclusive o que deve fazer com a resposta.